# Dualshock 4 touchpad without ds4drv

Tags: touchpad, gamepad

I was playing Towerfall: Ascension last night and realized that my Dualshock 4 controller was vibrating the way a 360 controller does. I tried Portal 2 and Sportsfriends... both games rumbled.

The rumble feature hasn't worked on any Linux distro since I bought this controller. However it's now working. I think it's cause I just upgraded my kernel which came with the new hid_sony driver and that gives me hope for my question.

Does anyone how to use the touchpad on the controller to move the cursor? Is this a feature the kernel devs have added to the hid_sony driver?

I've been able to use the ds4drv tool to get the touchpad to work, but it's buggy and hackish. I'd prefer to do things "natively" and permanently.

I'm running kernel 3.16.0-31-generic and Ubuntu GNOME 14.04

Thanks!